# System of equation solver

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am not sure if I should ask this here or in https://superuser.com/. Kindly redirect if the question needs to be moved.

I am looking for an online (or command line or software) tool where you just put a formulae with several unknown variables, then set the value of known variables and solve the unknowns if the information provided is enough.

For example, the following problem:

```
sin(x)=a+b
a=1
b=-0.2
```

The tool should output the value of x. And if I change to

```
sin(x)=a+b
a=1
x=3
```

It should detect that the unknown now becomes b to output the value of b.

I tried several tools but none can do this. I tried:

- [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/solve%20for%20x%2C%20sin%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%3Da%2Bb%2C%20a%3D1%2C%20b%3D-0.2?or=input) It does not arcsin x and gets confused on the second example.
- [QuickMath](https://quickmath.com/webMathematica3/quickmath/equations/solve/advanced.jsp#c=solve_solveequationsadvanced&v1=sin%2528x%2529%253Da%2Bb%250Aa%253D1%250Ab%253D-0.2&v2=x%250Aa%250Ab) Cannot solve
- [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=systems%20of%20equations%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf4EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation1%22%7D%20-%3E%22sin%28x%29%3Da%2Bb%2Bc%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf4EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation4%22%7D%20-%3E%22c%3D2%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22%20-%3E%20%7B%7B%22SolveSystemOf4EquationsCalculator%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf4EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation2%22%7D%20-%3E%22a%3D2%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf4EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation3%22%7D%20-%3E%22b%3D43%22) Can only solve 4 variables
- [Graspable Math](https://activities.graspablemath.com/whiteboards/_bf8145a988282d6c) Only tool that works but is not automatic. Needs to manually re-arrange the formula

Comment: you're looking for something like sagemath: https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/tour_algebra.html

You can try it out online with CoCalc: https://cocalc.com/ -- it's  a jupyter notebook style interface.

Create an an anonymous account and then looking at your projects and starting a new one.

Happy solving!

Comment: @User5678 thank you, I tried it and it's a great tool. However,  I don't seem to find the right syntax for my purpose. I tried `x = var('x')
a = var('a')
b = var('b')
solve([sin(x)==a+b, a==1,b==-0.2], x)` but it outputs nothing. I would appreciate if you could provide an example

Comment: Wolfram works fine for me. "solve sin(x)=a+b+c+d+e if a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4, e=5" and the solutions for x are given... "solve sin(x)=a+b+c+d+e if a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4, x=5" and the solution for e is given. edit: Your own link to wolfram even gives the solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of User5678, SageMath did this! I tried and it works and it is a wonderful tool because it works flawlessly with Python and Jupyter notebook. Thanks a lot of sharing.

> you're looking for something like sagemath:
> doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/tour_algebra.html You can try it out
> online with CoCalc: cocalc.com -- it's a jupyter notebook style
> interface.

Comment: Happy to help :-)